# How to prove that surface in $\mathbb{C}^3$ is not homemorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In my homology class I've got a following problem: I need to prove, that $X = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}^3: \ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0\}$  is not homemorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I have tried to delete point zero and show, that $ X \backslash \{0\}$ will not be connected, but I can't understand how this set looks like. I also tried to do something with homology of $X$ or $X \backslash \{0\}$, and I think, that it's an intendend way to solve this problem, but I didn't understand, how to do it.

So I want to ask: how to compute homology of such sets? Or mayby I should be looking in other direction?

Comment: Just asking, you don't mean $X = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb C^3\colon \ x^2+y^2+z^2=0\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I should probably edit it.

Comment: The partial derivatives vanish, so $X$ has a singularity at the origin. Don't know how to use that though. At least not yet :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. Let $x = u_1 + iv_1,\ y = u_2 + iv_2, \ z = u_3 + i v_3$. Consider vectors $u = (u_1,u_2,u_3),\ v = (v_1,v_2,v_3) \ \in \mathbb{R}^3$, then equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$ equivalent to the system

\begin{equation} 
   \begin{cases}
       |u|^2 - |v|^2 = 0 \\
       (u,v) = 0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Consider $X \backslash \{0\}$, then this system is equivalent to
\begin{equation} 
   \begin{cases}
       |\tilde{u}| = 1 \\
       (\tilde{u},v) = 0 \\
       v \neq 0
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{u} = \frac{u}{|v|}$

So $\tilde{u}$ lie in $\mathbb{S}^2$, and $v$ is tangent nonzero vector to $\tilde{u}$, thus $A \backslash \{0\}$ is homotopically equivalent to $T^1 \mathbb{S}^2 = \{ (u,v) \in T\mathbb{S}^2 \ : \ |v| = 1\}$ and it is known, that unit tangent bundle to $\mathbb{S}^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^3$.

Hence $X \backslash \{ 0\}$ is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^3$, but $\mathbb{C}^2 \backslash \{0\}$ is homotopically equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^3$, these spaces are not homotopically equivalent, thus initial spaces are not homemorphic.

I hope this solution will be useful to someone.